# boolValue not converting the NSString to BOOL

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, boolean

I know this doubt could be silly mistake.  I am getting  a variable from JSON string,  it will have the status 1 or 0.  If I do using first method(Code 1) it works.  But if I do the second method (Cord 2) I am getting NO always.  I don't know what am I doing wrong.  Please forgive me if the question is too silly.

**Cord 1:**

```
NSDictionary *drivingAlertResponse = [jsonResponseString objectFromJSONString];
BOOL isEnabled;
        if ([[drivingAlertResponse valueForKey:@"alertStatus"] intValue] > 0) {
            isEnabled = TRUE;
        }else{
            isEnabled = FALSE;
        }
```

**Cord 2:**

```
BOOL isEnabled = [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[drivingAlertResponse valueForKey:@"alertStatus"]] isEqualToString:@"1"]? @"TRUE": @"FALSE"   boolValue];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would just use NSString's [boolValue method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSString/boolValue). You can use it like so:

```
NSDictionary *drivingAlertResponse = [jsonResponseString objectFromJSONString];
BOOL isEnabled = [[drivingAlertResponse valueForKey:@"alertStatus"] boolValue];
```

Comment: Just what i needed

Answer (score 2):

`%i` is not a [valid format specifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1). To format an integer, you should use `%d`. However, at the point where you are doing that, you are trying to format `[drivingAlertResponse valueForKey:@"alertStatus"]` into an integer when it is still an object (possibly an NSString, or an NSNumber). The specifier for an *object* is `%@`. However, you could simply do `[[drivingAlertResponse valueForKey:@"alertStatus"] boolValue]` and be done with it, because both NSNumber and NSString have a boolValue method.

Comment: Thats because it is still an object - you'd need to do this to make it work: `isEnabled = [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[[drivingAlertResponse valueForKey:@"alertStatus"] intValue]] isEqualToString:@"1"]? @"TRUE": @"FALSE" boolValue]` But that whole thing is overly complicated when you can do `[[drivingAlertResponse valueForKey:@"alertStatus"] boolValue]`

Comment: Thank you.. verymuch.. the issue is because I missed intValue..  and my value is still an object.. thanks once again..

Answer (score 2):

```
BOOL value = YES = TRUE = 1 and value = NO = FALSE = 0
```

Do this:

```
BOOL isEnabled = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[drivingAlertResponse valueForKey:@"alertStatus"]] intValue];
```

Comment: u were getting alertStatus as string and needed to convert into int

Comment: boolValue will convert only int to BOOL ah?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using %i? if the value is 0 or 1 you should use %d.

You can try:

```
BOOL isEnabled = [drivingAlertResponse valueForKey:@"alertStatus"] != 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use

```
int returnBoolInt = [[drivingAlertResponse valueForKey:@"alertStatus"] intValue];

BOOL isEnabled = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:returnBoolStr] boolValue];
```